# How to disable special characters in angular Js input tag. Only allow alphanumeric(PAN Card Validation Regex)

Tags: angularjs

How to disable special characters in angular js input tag. Only allow alphanumeric
just like we use

```
<input type="text" ng-trim="false" style="text-transform: uppercase" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/" class="form-text" id="pan_card_number" name="pan_card_number" ng-minlength="10" maxlength="10" required ng-model="registration.newTSP.panCardNumber">
```

Comment: <input type="text" ng-trim="false" style="text-transform: uppercase" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/" class="form-text" id="pan_card_number" name="pan_card_number" ng-minlength="10" maxlength="10" required ng-model="registration.newTSP.panCardNumber">

Comment: any one please help me. how can i do it. I already using ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/" . But it allow in input text . i want to dissallow special character. Thanks for Advance

Comment: The actual pancard regex is 5 chars 4 digits and a trailing char. Have updated an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following

**Controller**

```
$scope.panCardRegex = '/[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}/i';
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="abc" ng-pattern="panCardRegex" />
```

Comment: Thanks Man .. Its Working (You are Awsome)

Comment: @ved-prakash Can you accept the answer, if this is working.

Comment: Yes i accepted this answer and also i put your code in my project ****Thanks a lot*****

Comment: How to disable space bar also

Comment: <input type="text" ng-trim="false" style="text-transform: uppercase" ng-pattern="/[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}/i" class="form-text" id="pan_card_number" name="pan_card_number" ng-minlength="10" maxlength="10" required ng-model="registration.newTSP.panCardNumber">
     <span class="bar"></span> <label>Company PAN card number (<span style="color: red;">*</span>) </label>

Answer (score 8):

you can use Regex with Ng-pattern and Display the message through ng-message

```
$scope.useOnlySpecialCharacters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;

<input type="text" ng-model="specialcharacters" 
ng-pattern="useOnlySpecialCharacters" />
```

show message through ng-message

```
<div ng-message="pattern"> Please Enter AlphaNumeric </div>
```

OR

Best Option is to use Directives

```
app.directive('noSpecialChar', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
        if (inputValue == null) {
          return '';
        }

        var cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
        if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
          modelCtrl.$render();
        }

        return cleanInputValue;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

[LINK](https://gist.github.com/tianes/0ad66a41d81727c702c7)

Comment: its so more complicated . I used ng-pattern = "/[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}/i" its a proper PAN card Number (regularExpression) ..  ans by liberalTGM

Comment: And to allow umlauts and other accented characters (Diacritics), use `/[^A-zÀ-ÿ\s]/gi` in the directive.

Answer (score 3):

use `ng-pattern="/[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}/i"` in your HTML input tag

Comment: Can help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888171/angular-text-box-avoid-only-1-special-character ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Use Directives to restrict Special characters: 

 angular.module('scPatternExample', [])
      .controller('scController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      }])
    .directive('restrictSpecialCharactersDirective', function() {
         function link(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
              ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
                var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
                if (viewValue.match(reg)) {
                  return viewValue;
                }
                var transformedValue = ngModel.$modelValue;
                ngModel.$setViewValue(transformedValue);
                ngModel.$render();
                return transformedValue;
              });
          }

          return {
              restrict: 'A',
              require: 'ngModel',
              link: link
          };      
      });


    <input type="text" ng-model="coupon.code" restrict-Special-Characters-Directive>
```

Answer (score 1):

set pattern to allow only alphanumeric

```
/^[a-z0-9]+$/i
```