# angular text box avoid only 1 special character

Tags: angular, regex, special-characters

Good day,

I have a requirement which is only need to not allow only 1 special character for user input, which is `~`. The following is my code:

```
<div class="form-input ">
          <input class="pass" [type]="'password'" name="newPassword"
            placeholder="New Password" required pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#&()-/$=<>?]).*$" #newPassword="ngModel"
            [(ngModel)]="newPassword" (ngModelChange)="checkNewPassword()"
            (click)="onInputFocus()" minlength={{changePasswordFormCriteria.minPwrdLength}}
            maxlength=30 (blur)="checkNewOldPassVal()">
          </div>
        </div>

<div *ngIf="newPassword.errors?.pattern && loginPasswordForm.submitted" class="form-errors">
          New Password must consist at least one uppercase, one lowercase letter, one number and one special characters within this range ! @ # & ( ) - ? / $ = < >
        </div>
```

As you can see, I exclude the `~` character from the `pattern`. This is work if I only key in only 1 special character `~`, for example, "password~abc", this will prompt the error message in `newPassword.errors?.pattern`. This is correct and this is match with requirement.

However, if I include other special character, for example, I key in "password@~abc", this will not prompt error message, it will allow to go through. I am wondering I not include the `~` in the pattern, but not sure why it still can pass through.

May I know what mistake I did?

Comment: You are focusing too much on the tilda character (`'~'`). I doubt that you want `'μ'` or `'ع'` either. In place of `.*$` at the end you need  a character class containing all valid characters that is executed one or more times, followed by an end-of-string anchor: `[<all valid characters go here>]+$` (or `[...]*$` or `[...]{4,}$`, as all valid strings must contain at least four characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you have used only make sure that the string input contains the expression provided. It does not enforce the exclusion of ~ from the input.

You may want to try this instead

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#&()\-/$=<>?])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#&()\-/$=<>?]+$
```

One more thing, in this part of your regex

> ...[!@#&()**-**/$=<>?]...

You got to delimit the hyphen(-), else it will allow characters ranging from ascii 41-47. It should look something like this

> ...[!@#&()\-/$=<>?]...

Or simply add the hyphen to the beginning or end as @Cary had pointed out.

Comment: Sory, I miss out 1 requirement. Yes, I need to make sure the input contains the expression. In the same time, want to eclude the ~. Any way I can do this? The requirement is same like the error message "New Password must consist at least one uppercase, one lowercase letter, one number and one special characters within this range ! @ # & ( ) - ? / $ = < >", means at least 1 special character as well, except ~

Comment: My bad, the previous example didnt work as expected. The updated one should be working as intended.

Comment: Wonderful. This is work. Thanks for your help. I am new to angular, sometimes I found that I am really hard to find out this thing in google, I am actually having a lot of angular frontend issue at my site, I hope that I can continue learn from you in future.

Comment: You can put the hyphen at the beginning or end of the character class without escaping it.